# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txtText=" <h4>test<")

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below snippet:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="txtText" value=" " />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="GetData()" runat="server" 
            onclick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
   <script>
       function GetData() {
           $('[id$=txtData]').val(escape($('input[name="txtText"]').val()))
           //$('input[name="txtText"]').val('')
       }
   </script>
    </form>
    </body>
```

When I input some data like "`<h4>Test</h4>`" it throws an exception, however, the code is working fine when the line `//$('input[name="txtText"]').val('')` is un-commented.

Can somebody please help me here and explain what is really happening here?

Comment: Are you using any kind of WYSIWYG plugin for `txtData`? Something that allows a user to write text but actually writes HTML to the underlying form control?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client?rq=1

Comment: The code is not giving out any errors when you add normal text. It is a specific scenario that you mentioned in your subject line where you tried to supply html code.

Comment: Yes i am using  WYSIWYG plugin for txtText and before submit i provide encoded data of txtText html input control to a hidden server control  like txtData here

Answer (score 0):

This is to protect you from [XSS(cross site scripting)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.

if you do not need it, you can disabled it by:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

or:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or to handle it manually, you need to encode html before submitting form:

```
void submitForm(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(textbox.Text)); 
}
```

and on submit button:

```
<asp:Button id="submitbutton" runat="server" onclick="submitForm" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: Can you shed some light on onclick event? Is it client side or server side? ClientSide  you wouldn't have those methods, and on server side you wouldn't reach the event.

Comment: @KartheekN give it a try! it is server sided event.